# Can't access http://localhost:3000 after setting up webrick server with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cmd, localhost, webrick

I followed this tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and I get to the part where you write:

```
rails server
```

Then, when I tried to access http:/localhost:3000 I had an "access denied" error. I already tried:

- accessing http:// my-ip:3000, http:// 127.0.0.1:3000, http:// 0.0.0.0:3000 (the spaces are because I'm not allowed to post links)
- opening the 3000 port in the firewall settings
- trying again from a different browser/computer

What can I do to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: check in terminal if your server is even running or not?

Comment: Can you paste the error message that you got in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to login before?

It can be if you did by "Getting started" page you have "cookies" with wrong credentials.

Can you check your browser cookies and remove all for "your-ip", localhost, 127.0.0.1 with 300 port?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I deleted all cookies and I got a "This webpage is not available" error. Is this what you meant? Also, what did you mean by login? There was no login involved in the setup process.

Comment: Now, it looks like your rails server is not working or it's on another port.